# Make a function that reads as input only a matrix with 2 columns

Tags: r

So I built my own function to remove missing values from a matrix:

```
removeMiss <- function(data) {
  removed <<- data[complete.cases(data), ]
  return(mat_NA_removed)
}
```

But I want to condition the function to work only with 2 column matrices

Comment: can you please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not perfect but does what you want.
First, some test data, since you haven't provided a dataset. One of the matrices has 2 columns, the other one has 3.

```
set.seed(7201)
mat1 <- 1:24
mat1[sample(24, 5)] <- NA
mat2 <- mat1
dim(mat1) <- c(12, 2)
dim(mat2) <- c(8, 3)
```

Now, the code.

```
removeMiss <- function(data) {
    dataname <- deparse(substitute(data))
    if(!inherits(data, "matrix"))
        stop(paste(sQuote(dataname), "is not an object of class 'matrix'"))
    if(ncol(data) == 2){
        data <- data[complete.cases(data), ]
    } else {
        warning(paste("Matrix", sQuote(dataname), "does not have 2 columns"))
    }
    data
}

removeMiss(mat1)
removeMiss(mat2)
```

Notes:

1. The function issues an error if the object `data` is not of class `matrix`;
2. It issues a warning if the matrix `data` does not have exactly 2 columns.

In the case `data` doesn't have 2 columns, it is not changed, meaning, if there are `NA`values they will **not** be removed.